# How to Sort and Move Files Based on their Extensions on Windows

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe, sorting, file-extension

I'm trying to sort and move files based on their extensions within Windows, and am following this [tutorial](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-sort-and-move-files-based-on-their-extensions-on-windows/) using:

```bat
@echo off
    
for %%a in (".\*") do (
  if "%%~xa" NEQ "" if "%%~dpxa" NEQ "%~dpx0" (
    if not exist "%%~xa" mkdir "%%~xa" (
      move "%%a" "%%~dpa%%~xa\"
    )
  )
)
```

- I converted the `.txt` file into `.bat` file, however the batch file doesn't do anything when I double click to open it; it does open when I try to run it as Admin, but I get an access denied error

Am I doing anything wrong, as I followed the exact steps?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Is the **.bat** file located in the same folder all the files are located?

Comment: Hello :) yes it is in the same location

Comment: Can you try to edit the **.bat** file (Right-click>Edit) and add at the end a new line with the word `pause`. Save the file and then run again. It should run, but show you the output and errors. What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```all-bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f delims^= %%a in =;('where .:*.* ^| find /v /i "%~0"'
  )do 2>nul =;( mkdir "%%~xa" & move "%%a" "%%~dpa%%~xa\" );=
```

---

> *Am I doing anything wrong, as I followed the exact steps?*
>
> - You are using a solution that supposedly serves the author.

Choose to try something more specific:

**1.** List your files that contain extensions and already excluding bat, usind `where` to list only files that **contain .eXtensions**. It obeys the search filter by **All Files** + **All eXtensions**. and usingwith `find /v /i "%~0"` to exclude your bat from being listed.

```all-bat
where .:*.* ^| find /v /i "%~0"
```

---

**2.** `NEQ` is for condition `if 1 NEQ 2 ()` operand comparison between INTEGER, not string.

```all-bat
if "%%~xa" NEQ "" if "%%~dpxa" NEQ "%~dpx0" (
...
```

**3.** Execute the action of creating a folder directly, if it exists the warning is omitted and without any impact on the rest of the execution and will not even interrupt the current loop

```all-bat
 2>nul =;( mkdir "%%~xa" & move "%%a" "%%~dpa%%~xa\" );=
```

---

**Obs.1:** When trying to open a folder where one already exists, the system just returns a simple warning "the folder already exists", and continues without interrupting the execution of bat.

```all-bat
2>nul mkdir "already exists"
```

---

**Obs.2:** Using ***`cd /d "%~dp0"`*** because the files and bat are supposed to be in the same folder, otherwise edit and replace ***"%~dp0"*** with a qualified path:

```all-bat
@echo off && cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Folder"
...
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`CD /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

  - [`CD /d "%~dp0"`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)
- [`Where /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How to set multiple `Delims`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383845/how-to-set-multiple-delims)
- [Why do you need `"tokens"` and `"delims"` in `"for"`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2319)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)